# Caching flickr images in twig templates

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've created a symfony 2 blog which includes photos from flickr dependent on the date of the post.

I was originally calling the api in the controller which was very expensive (new to this). I am now grabbing the photos each time the post is edited and recompiling the post's body template down to html and including it in a parent template.

If I make an edit to the body template itself, I have to compile everything via a command.

Is there a better way to handle invalidating individual templates and have them re compile once on the fly in a production environment? I.e. Storing the related picture urls in a database and updating that instead? (Once the post is live, it's very unlikely that photos will be added for this time period.)